# I need to split a mysql field (string) by multiple delimeters into json object

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I inherited a mysql database and am trying to migrate it to mongodb.  There is a field called `details` that contains some key value "pairs" I want to split up.  There could be a single key/value pair, or  multiple pairs split by multiple delimiters.  I put pairs in quotes because they are formatted strangely.  They are delimited by colon `:` and key values split by commas `,`.  For example here is the value of one such field:

`Normal Duty,5min:Heavy Duty,10min:Riser,10max:`

This is 3 key value pairs, delimited by the colon.  I want to get these into a json object if possible, like this:

```
{
   'Normal Duty': '5min',
   'Heavy Duty': '10min',
   'Riser': '10max'
}
```

I think I could do it using substring_index if it were only a single key/value pair that had a single delimiter, but I get lost trying to think of a way to extract multiple key/value pairs with multiple delimiters.   I'm able to get a count of the number of delimiters, `SELECT id, details, LENGTH(details) - LENGTH(REPLACE(details, ':', '')) AS COUNT FROM type` but not sure how I could use that number in a loop or something.

Comment: @Akina, no, they could contain 1, or 3 or 6 or 7 or even 0.  Any number of pairs, really.

Comment: @Akina the data is currently in a MySQL database version 5.7.28

Comment: @Akina the max number I'm seeing is 6 pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT test.id, 
       JSON_OBJECTAGG(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.value, ':', numbers.num), ':', -1), ',', 1),
                      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.value, ':', numbers.num), ':', -1), ',', -1))
FROM test
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION
             SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 ) numbers
WHERE numbers.num <= LENGTH(test.value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(test.value, ':', ''))
GROUP BY test.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d10261e21a0fb1c1060091e8b4e58d80

Adjust `numbers` subquery if the amount of key-value pairs may be above 6.

PS. To work with JSON I'd strongly recommend to upgrade your server.